# Update local storage Expo React Native for TestFlight

Tags: react-native, expo, local-storage, testflight, eas

I have an issue when uploading Expo React Native builds to TestFlight. I'm building an app and update the objects stored in Expo SecureStore rather often, because I find I need new fields now and then. However, when I upload the build to TestFlight, it comes up as a blank screen, because the current stored object has fields missing that the code is looking for. **How can I automatically clear the SecureStore fields before uploading the build to TestFlight?**

For context, this is a simple app with no database, just data saved to local storage, and I don't have a pipeline or anything set up yet. I just run the `eas build -p ios` command and use transporter for now.

I think I need some sort of migration script, but I don't know how to set that up, as I'm pretty new to building mobile apps in production. Thanks ahead of time.